# Vue class-based-components Extends And Mixins

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Hello how can I convert this component in a class-based-component using typescript?

```
<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { chartLast30Days, chartStylingMethods } from '#/mixins'
import { myChartOptions } from '#/const/charts'

export default {
    extends: Line,
    mixins: [chartLast30Days, chartStylingMethods],
    props: { chartPointsDownloads: Array, chartPointsPlays: Array, chartPointsSales: Array },        
}
</script>
```

Comment: check this out 
https://johnpapa.net/vue-typescript/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can give you some code examples for creating class based components using the vue property decorator, extending classes and use mixins.

### Vue component, class based:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class MyClass extends Vue {
    created() {
        console.log("Created MyClass");
    }
}
</script>
```

### Extend an existing class:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import MyClass from './MyClass';
@Component
export default class MyExtendingClass extends MyClass {
  created() {
    console.log("Created MyExtendingClass");
  }
}
</script>
```

### Creating a mixin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
@Component
export default class MyMixin extends Vue {
  myMixinValue = 'Fetch my mixin';
}
```

### Inject mixins to component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import MyClass from './MyClass';
import MyMixin from './MyMixin';
@Component({
  mixins: [MyMixin]
})
export default class MyExtendingClass extends MyClass {
  created() {
    console.log("Created MyExtendingClass");
    console.log(this.myMixinValue);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have vue project in class based typescript. And try to create simple extends. Base on your code, its work OLNY if `MyClass` is a pure `.ts` file.

In a case like your example, when you add some `public foo: string = 'some value'` to `MyClass`, it will not be visible in `MyExtendingClass`. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe your converter (webpack, vue-cli, typescript) ignores vue files for converting to JS? If you write typescript in a vue files, the script tag is import --> <script lang="ts">

Comment: I need to add some properties an methods to all of my compoennts Witch method is prefered? Mixins or inheritence?

Comment: Thank you for ```@Component({ mixins: [ component ] })```
I have a .ts file with a class that extends vue in it, and it sits in a git submodule.
Root git repo vue project class components just wouldn't extend from it unless I did that.
Simply put:
```@Component
class b extends a```
wouldn't work, but this would
```@Component({ mixins: [a] })
class b extends a```
Class `a` sits in the git submodule in a .ts file while b tries to extend from it and has .vue extension

Hope this helps someone. Any doc links regarding this?